# 3 inline- box with same size & height in middle of the page which should be responsive and for mobile view it show the same as desktop

Tags: html

[Dashboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqYWM.png)
Please here See the img

Is there any other way to write the below code & on all screen it should show same view.

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 offset-md-3">
        <div class="row">               
          <div class="col-2"><a href="#" ><button style="width: 100px; height: 40px; border: solid 3px #ff4040;border-radius:  25px; background-color: white;color: #ff4040;" >Load</button></a></div>


         <div class="col-2">
            <small class="text-muted">Avl. Bal.</small>
            <p>&#8377 2,000</p>
         </div>


    <div class="col-2"><a href="#"><button style="width: 100px; height: 40px; border: solid 3px #ff4040;border-radius:  25px; background-color: white;color: #ff4040;" >Send</button></a></div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set width for each and every column to the value **33.33333333%**

`.col-2{
    width:33.33333333%
}`

Comment: Keep a wrapper `div` and set a width in viewport. Why don't you write media query if it's complex to understand

Comment: yes want to write the media query but not understand how to write?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp  Please refer this link and get an idea about media query. Also you can use **bootstrap** for your problem

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it but still issue with the mobile view, it shows space on the right side does not come in the middle of the page. 
Any solution for this?

```
<div class="col-6 offset-md-3 offset-sm-6 " >
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                <div class="d-flex align-content-center justify-content-center;" style="border: 1px solid;border-radius: 5px; ">             
                    <div class="col-4" style="border-right :1px solid;">
                        <a href="#" ><button style="width: 100%; height: 40px; border: solid 1px #ff4040;border-radius:  25%; background-color: white;color: #ff4040;margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 20px;" >Load</button></a></div>


                <div class="col-4" style="border-right: 1px solid;">
                    <small class="text-muted">Avl. Bal.</small>
                    <p>&#8377 2,000</p>
                 </div>


                <div class="col-4"  ><a href="#"><button style="width: 100%; height: 40px; border: solid 1px #ff4040;border-radius:  25%; background-color: white;color: #ff4040;margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 20px;" >Send</button></a></div>

                    </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class=" col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>

    </div>

</div>
```